# Set main language in Jekyll

Tags: localization, jekyll, liquid

How can I change the default language in Jekyll? I would like, to have German names for the days using the `{{ … | date "%A" }}` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the [`i18n_filter`](https://github.com/gacha/gacha.id.lv/blob/master/_plugins/i18n_filter.rb) plug-in together with the localization of choice from [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) in `_locales` did the trick.

The filter is used by simply writing e.g.

```
{{ post.date | localize: "%A, %-d.%m.%Y %k.%M Uhr" }}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Jekyll Date Formatting Examples](http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples) by Alan Smith

#### _includes/date-ge.html

```
<!-- Whitespace added for readability -->
{% assign m = include.date | date: "%-m" %}
{{ include.date | date: "%-d" }}
{% case m %}
  {% when '1' %}Januar
  {% when '2' %}Februar
  {% when '3' %}M&auml;rz
  {% when '4' %}April
  {% when '5' %}Mai
  {% when '6' %}Juni
  {% when '7' %}Juli
  {% when '8' %}August
  {% when '9' %}September
  {% when '10' %}Oktober
  {% when '11' %}November
  {% when '12' %}Dezember
{% endcase %}
{{ include.date | date: "%Y" }}
```

Now instead of `page.date` or `post.date` you can call this include and pass it date as an argument.

```
{% include date-ge.html date=page.date %}
```

Comment: This seams to be quite unhandy if you want to use dates at multiple places.

Comment: Jekyll includes are made for factorization. Edited my answer